# do the planes of electron orbits make an angle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, particle-physics

if we think as the electrons around the atoms classically, then as the two electrons in the first shell (1s) go around the nucleus; do the planes of orbit make an angle with each other (as an average) or not?

Comment: i think there should not be an angle, because an atom with a filled shell has no net magnetic moment (if the nucleus is ignored).

Comment: Do not think about electrons in atoms classically. It will make you very unhappy.

Comment: they are symmetric as we can see in the orbital pictures... but do they produce equal and opposite magnetic moments... !! as it seems, yes. ?!! but i have not found a convincing explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's risky to think about subatomic particles in a classical way, but maybe we can get something from it if we're careful.

Electrons orbiting an atom in a state with well-defined angular momentum quantum number $\ell$ have wavefunctions described by the [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics).
The $s$ shell, with $\ell=0$, has spherical symmetry; this state really is fundamentally different from a classical orbit, because it *cannot* be oriented.

The $p$ shell, with $\ell=1$, is orientable.
We must define coordinates: 
let's use cartesian and spherical coordinates $\vec r = (x,y,z) = (r,\theta,\phi)$, 
quantized relative to the $z$-axis,
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec r$ and the $z$-axis,
and $\phi$ is the angle between the $x$-axis and the projection of $\vec r$ onto the $x$-$y$ plane.
The spherical harmonics for the two states with nonzero projection $m$ on the quantization axis are
$$
Y_1^{\pm1} (\theta,\phi) \propto e^{\pm i\phi}\sin\theta 
$$
Wavefunctions with this angular term have maximum amplitude in the $x$-$y$ plane, where $\theta$ is a quarter-turn from the $z$-axis.
The *total* wavefunction is
$$
\psi = R_{n\ell}(r) \cdot Y_\ell^m(\theta,\phi) \cdot e^{i\omega t}
$$
where the energy of the state is $E=\hbar\omega$. As the state evolves in time, then, the phase of the $\ell=1,m=\pm1$ states advances around the origin in the $x$-$y$ plane, but whether the advance in phase is clockwise or counterclockwise depends on the sign of $m$.  It certainly seems attractive to say that the two $m=\pm1$ electrons are orbiting the atom in the same plane but in opposite directions!
It's quite analogous to the one-dimensional plane wave $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$, where the direction of the [probability current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current) is given by the direction of advancing phase.

Note that the spherical harmonic for $m=0$ is real; that state does not have a probability current and we cannot immediately compare it to a classical orbit. 
However, the rules for transforming angular momentum under rotations tell us that the $\ell=1,m_z=0$ state can be written as a superposition of $\ell=0,m_x=\pm1$ states quantized along a different axis.

If we want two electrons possibly orbiting in different planes, we need more degrees of freedom than the $p$ shell offers.
The $d$ shell, with $\ell=2$, corresponds to the spherical harmonics
\begin{align}
Y_2^{\pm2} &\propto e^{\pm2i\phi} \sin^2\theta
\\
Y_2^{\pm1} &\propto e^{\pm i\phi} \sin\theta\cos\theta
\end{align}
The $|m|=2$ case is similar to the $p$-shell analysis we just did, except more strongly peaked in the $x$-$y$ plane.
The $|m|=1$ case is more complicated to visualize. (And most internet visualizations show the real spherical harmonics, which don't have definite $m$.)
The $|m|=1$ wavefunction is nonzero on two cones about the $z$-axis.
At a given $\phi$ the two cones are exactly out of phase with each other, but the direction in which the phase advances about the $z$-axis is given by the sign of $m$. So an $\ell=2,m=1$ electron is *not* orbiting in a skewed plane; it's in a superposition of two nonclassical orbits, parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane but not centered on the nucleus. A surprising image! Perhaps someone will help me make an illustration.

These two arguments are all we need to get to higher $\ell$; the only difference is the number of cones, their opening angles, and the presence or absence of a wavefunction component in the $x$-$y$ plane.

If there *were* two electron orbits which had well-defined $m$ in different planes, those orbitals would be eigenstates of projection operators $L_z$ and $L_x$ which do not commute.  I think you do not get the privilege of quantizing the spins of each electron in an atom separately, so having electrons in well-defined skewed planes is forbidden.

Comment: you know that for investigating magnetic properties of different materials we assign magnetic momentum to atoms and electrons and we can study them classically. i want to make a visual image of this classical study. and i think it helped. thanks

Answer (score 3):

If we think as electrons around atoms classically, then electrons would irradiate electromagnetic energy, losing momentum and thus collapsing into the nucleus, and atoms couldn't exist. Therefore your question makes no sense.

The correct description of an atom is using quantum mechanics, which means there is no [orbits](http://www.sciencekids.co.nz/images/pictures/chemistry/hydrogenatom.jpg) on atoms. There is only the solution of Schrödinger's equation, that is, the [wave function](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Hydrogen_Density_Plots.png) of atoms.